# Object not passed to jQuery Dialog OnSubmit handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="referenceResolverDialog" title="Resolve IDs">
    <p>Please fill in a comma separated list of IDs.</p>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <textarea name="referenceResolverTextArea" id="referenceResolverTextArea" rows="6" cols="54"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I created the jQuery dialog as follow:

```
var configParams = {
    // some config properties
    textAreaSelector: '#referenceResolverTextArea',
    // some other config properties
}

var form, dialog;

dialog = $(configParams.dialogSelector).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 220,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Resolve": ResolveDialogData,
        Cancel: function () {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        form[0].reset();
        dialog.dialog("close");
    }
});

form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ResolveDialogData(configParams);
});
```

The problem is that `configParams` is passed as a new object, not the object I have already. In the `ResolveDialogData()` method I have as follow:

```
function ResolveDialogData(configParams) {
    alert(configParams); // returns [object Object]
    alert(configParams.textAreaSelector); // returns undefined
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hitting that callback from your "Resolve" button, your `configParams` parameter will represent the `Event` object passed by your dialog.

Change

```
buttons: {
        "Resolve": ResolveDialogData,
        Cancel: function () {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
```

to

```
buttons: {
        "Resolve": function(e) { // e is the object you were ending up with before 
            ResolveDialogData(configParams); 
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! My assumption was that it should be configured on the form onsubmit.